# Is it acceptable to consume an external API with WEB API HttpClient and then show deserialized result in angular?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to retrieve the content of a JSON feed. I want to use `HttpClient` for downloading the content. For this purpose I've created a WEB API controller with a `Get` method which consumes the external API with `HttpClient` and then returns a `List` of deserialized content:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("externalAPI");
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType =
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    List<MyClass> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content);
    return data;
}
```

Now I'm going to show this list in client side using Angular and I know how should I do these steps but my question is why should I use a WEB API to consume another external API since I can simply use Angular `HttpClient` to consume that external API? Is using this WEB API to consume an external API and then return a `List` to Angular considered as best practices? If no, what is the best way, if **I have to use MVC for this purpose**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I consumed external API (which retuns json data), via webapi.

I did it because than my Angular project only have to maintain reference to webapi only i.e. just one url only. and another case in my project is external api url change in Dev,UAT and prod evironment, so i dont want to maintain in my angular project.

So I did it for two reason

1. Dont want to maintain reference of external api (i.e. URL of external api), and I get only one contact for getting data in my project which is my webapi
2. URL of external API change in Dev, UAT and PRod so I dont want to maintain that information in my Angular project.
3. That makes my code of angular more maintainable as if someone else look my code he/she get info that webapi is only location where they should look for ,from where data is coming

Imagine scenario where you are geting data from more then one external API, in that case you have to maintain reference to all API in your Angualr project. So Better to Follow **FACADE design pattern**, and keep only one point (which WebAPI in this case) which connect with all external api and returns data.

---

For getting data every 10 min you need to make use of RxJs

```
var timer$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000) // 1000 = 1 second

timer$
  .subscribe((v)=> this.Service.CalltoExtnerlAPIToGetdata()
             .subscribe(data=> this.values = data));
```

please do unsubscribe from Rxjs Timer when you are not going to consume it to avoid memory leak.. http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables

Comment: Thanks. I should also mention that retrieving the list of the `MyClass` should only happens once every 10 minutes. Does this fact considerable? Also can you please give me a clue of how can I retrieve the list every 10 minute?

Comment: @J.P - you need to make call from angular every 10 min right ?

Comment: Actually, I have to call the external API every 10 min and there is no difference that I call from angular or my WEB API. I want to know if we consider this fact, is WEB API still the best choice?

Comment: @J.P - you need to use RxJs libarary for making call every 10 min

Comment: which tool should I use, if I want to make this repeating call from my WEB API?

Comment: @J.P - updated answer for Typescript , From WebAPI you should make use of `Timer`

Comment: But by using RxJs you are calling our WEB API. Is it supposed to call the external API also if our consuming function be in our WEB API because as I said I need to repeat calling external API?

Comment: @J.P - you should make use of RXJs in angular ... that is ok rather then doing call from webapi every 10 min ...

Comment: @J.P - yes you hsould make call to webapi using RxJs

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your thorough answer and explanation. So as a conclude, you suggest that I call the external API in my WEB API, and then by using angular call my web api and finally by using RxJs repeat calling external api? Correct?

Comment: @J.P - yes ... that is only good way i suggest

Comment: @J.P - and please do unsubscribe from Rxjs Timer when you are not going to consume it to avoid memory leak.. http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Comment: So just calling `unsubscribe` is enough? Can you show it's usage with your code?

Comment: @J.P - yes or you can use way given in article

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this external API is in the domain abc.com and your app is in the yourapp.com. If abc.com doesn't allow CORS (cross origin request), you won't be able to retrieve data from your angular app that is running in yourapp.com, so buildind a "middleware" in a server might solve this problem.

Anyway, it's not mandatory to build this middleware. If the target API allows CORS, there is no need to do this, and you can write the layer that requests data in your angular app.

Comment: Thanks. So if I have to use MVC for this purpose, wouldn't it be better to use MVC core and Razor view instead of using Angular at all? I am looking for a way that is best for this purpose by considering this fact that I have to use MVC.

Comment: What you will use in the frontend (angular, razor view, any other template engine, react, whatever) is something that is your choice. There is no "best choice". Anyway, Angular is best suited for SPA and the template is rendered in the browser (of course, if you are not dealing with server-side rendering, that is another topic, inside the "isomorphic javascript"). If you are already using an MVC framework with a server side template rendering and will not take advantage of Angular, I don't see any reason to use it.

Comment: I should also mention that retrieving the list of the `MyClass` should only happen once every 10 minutes. Does this fact considerable? Also can you please give me a clue of how can I retrieve the list every 10 minute?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason lies within the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) where a given origin, e.g. script executed by your browser, is only allowed to perform requests to an origin which is in the same domain (schema, host and port).
Reasons are mainly security related and have been extensively discussed in [this StackExchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important).

A typical approach in MVC implementations to comply to this policy is to perform the HTTP request to your WebAPI using server side code, i.e. from the Controller using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx). Then the Javascript from your View would simply call your Controller's method to retrieve the result.

As a side note, this approach has also the benefit of let you handle any serialization work in your Controller before presenting the data back to the View.